# Get number of bits in char

Tags: c++

How do I get the number of bits in type `char`?

I know about `CHAR_BIT` from `climits`. This is described as »The macro yields the maximum value for the number of bits used to represent an object of type char.« at [Dikumware's C Reference](http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/?manual=compleat&page=limits.html#CHAR_BIT). I understand that means the number of bits in a `char`, doesn't it?

Can I get the same result with `std::numeric_limits` somehow? `std::numeric_limits<char>::digits` returns `7` correctly but unfortunately, because this value respects the signedness of the 8-bit char here…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to be overly specific, you can do this:

```
sizeof(char) * CHAR_BIT
```

If you know you are definitely going to do the sizeof char, it's a bit overkill as sizeof(char) is guaranteed to be 1.

But if you move to a different type such as wchar_t, that will be important.

Answer (score 15):

`CHAR_BIT` is, by definition, number of bits in the *object representation* of type `[signed/unsigned] char`.

[`numeric_limits<>::digits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits) is the number of non-sign bits in the *value representation* of the given type.

Which one do you need?

If you are looking for number of bits in the object representation, then the correct approach is to take the `sizeof` of the type and multiply it by `CHAR_BIT` (of course, there's no point in multiplying by `sizeof` in specific case of `char` types, since their size is always 1, and since `CHAR_BIT` by definition alredy contains what you need).

If you are talking about value representation then `numeric_limits<>` is the way to go.

For `unsigned char` type the bit-size of object representation (`CHAR_BIT`) is guaranteed to be the same as bit-size of value representation, so you can use `numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits` and `CHAR_BIT` interchangeably, but this might be questionable from the conceptual point of view.

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention why I was not content with using CHAR_BIT: I would like to get the number of bits in some templated code, and numeric_limits<> would fit in better in my first view. But the approach of using sizeof(char) * CHAR_BIT as mentioned by R Samuel Klatchko does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the snippets archive for this code [here](http://c.snippets.org/snip_lister.php?fname=bitcnt_1.c), here's an adapted version, I do not claim this code:

```
int countbits(char ch){
    int n = 0;
    if (ch){
        do n++;
        while (0 != (ch = ch&(ch-1)));
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no reputation here yet so I'm not allowed to reply to @t0mm13b 's answer, but wanted to point out that there's a problem with the code:

```
int countbits(char ch){
    int n = 0;
    if (ch){
        do n++;
        while (0 != (ch = ch&(ch-1)));
    }
    return n;
}
```

The above won't count the number of bits in a character, it will count the number of set bits (1 bits).

For example, the following call will return 4:

```
char c = 'U';
countbits(c);
```

The code:

```
ch = ch & (ch - 1)
```

Is a trick to strip off the right most (least significant) bit that's set to 1. So, it glosses over any bits set to 0 and doesn't count them.